# In numpy savetxt function, what does the 'newline' parameter do?

Tags: text, numpy, save

I'm using the savetxt function (description [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)) to save a matrix to a txt file, and I wonder what does the 'newline' parameter do? Also the 'header' parameter doesn't seem to work with the latest numpy version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for setting how the end of a line is represented for interoperability between Mac/Linux/Windows.

Windows typically represents a line end with a carriage return character followed by a linefeed character (\r\n).

Mac used to use just a carriage return, and much Microsoft Mac software still saves files this way, but has used a linefeed for the past decade or so (\n).

Linux has always used a linefeed as far as I know (\n).

Comment: oh! that's what it is! Thanks! so will I have a problem copying the data file between Windows and Mac?

Comment: As this has been a problem for the past ~2 decades, much software has adapted to accept either style.  If the particular software you're using doesn't, there are numerous conversion utilities out there.  Search 'mac windows newline conversion' or similar.